# Removing texmf/doc/ directories from old TeXlives

Tags: texlive, installing, tds

I have got quite a lot of vanilla TeXlives installed, and some of them with the full documentation. Can I "break" TeXlive by removing the `*/doc` directories from it? Currently, I would save this way `3.3G`, which is already quite significant to me:

```
[texlive]$ du -shc */*/doc/
6.8M    2010/texmf-dist/doc/
216K    2010/texmf/doc/
5.0M    2011/texmf-dist/doc/
216K    2011/texmf/doc/
5.5M    2012/texmf-dist/doc/
216K    2012/texmf/doc/
1.6G    2013/texmf-dist/doc/
1.7G    2014/texmf-dist/doc/
1.7G    2015/texmf-dist/doc/
4.9G    total
```

Comment: texdoc will no longer work in such installations. But beside this what should break?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That part I understand (and I don't use it anyways). A I don't know. that's why I ask...

Answer (score 12):

Removing the `doc` hierarchy will not break anything but `texdoc` searching for documentation.

But simple removal will bring back the documentation for each updated packages. If you want to stop installing documentation files in the future, you can set the `tlmgr` configuration option to not install doc files with `tlmgr option docfiles 0`. After that documentation files will not be installed.

If you want to get the documentation of a single package, you can use `tlmgr install --reinstall --with-doc <PKG>` to reinstall that single package *with* documentation, regardless of the current setting of `docfiles`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good to know. So removing `doc` from old distributions of course will not end up with them reappearing, since they won't get updated.

Answer (score 6):

Since installing without documentation is an available option in the TeX Live installer, there seems no reason to assume that removing these `doc` folders will have any ill effects  apart from `texdoc` not working.

Here's a quote of a message by Reinhard Kotucha from  the [TeX Live Mailing list](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2012-February/031090.html)

> From: Reinhard Kotucha
>
> On 2012-02-17 at 20:57:33 +0100, Pander wrote:
>
> > Hi all,
> >
> > What is the proper way to install TeX Live without texmf-dist/doc
> >     which takes up about 1.1 GB
>
> If you are using the text-mode installer, go to the options menu
>
> ```
>  <O> options:
>     [ ] use letter size instead of A4 by default
>     [X] allow execution of restricted list of programs via \write18
>     [X] create all format files
>     [X] install macro/font doc tree
>     [X] install macro/font source tree
> ```
>
> and disable the option "install macro/font doc tree".
>
> Reinhard

Further in the same thread, it is clear that the `doc` (and source) trees can be removed from an existing distribution too:

> > Thanks. I asked indeed for install but also needed to know how to do
> >     this on an existing installation.
>
> Call tlmgr option ... to set the `nosource` and `ndoc` option, and then
>   reinstall either all packages, or remove the doc and source tree.

Comment: The problem is, these are **old** installs. I needed the doc back then, but I don't need them anymore.

Comment: @yo' Sure, but what  I mean is since it's an option to *not* install the docs, then removing the docs in your old installs won't have any bad effects, since you could easily have not installed them in the first place.

Comment: Well, even if you don't install the documentation, there's couple MB of data in teh `doc` folder...

Comment: @yo' Like what? Have you got one installation that chose that option when you installed?

Comment: Yes I have. I'll report tomorrow, now I'm at a different computer.

Comment: @yo' Some packages put files which you might want to use into the `doc` directory. So to use them, you have to move them somewhere else, but they are there. However, it seems unlikely that TeX Live filters for this when packaging as it would mean examining every package's documentation to see if it contained this kind of material.

Comment: @cfr I don't think that anyone puts required material in the `doc` tree, although for sure there are sample documents and other things that might appear there.  If someone has done that they've done things wrong...

Comment: @AlanMunn I've seen things in the `doc` tree which are 'extras'. So they aren't strictly required to use the main package or class, but they might be needed to use some particular additional feature. There was something like this for a thumb index, for example, but I can't remember the package or class. (It didn't work properly anyway, so it wouldn't have been that great a loss. But I suppose it worked at some point.)

Comment: Ah ok, it seems that it's only `man1` (man page for the binaries) and manual to KOMA, so I should be fine. Well, for now I renamed the folders to `doc_remove` so that whoever is looking won't find anything, and I'll see :)

Comment: Since files in below the doc directory are not searched by kpathsea, all the files cannot contribute at all to the system. If they provide functionality, the files have to be copied somewhere else. But in TeX Live we try hard that something like this is not necessary.